# Iterate over query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to iterate over a query that I just generated and execute triggers bit it seems Postgres doesn't recognize what I want to do,how can I fix it?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_rezultz() RETURNS VOID AS
   $BODY$

    BEGIN
 FOR r IN (SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER ' || tab_name|| '_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ' || tab_name|| ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ' AS trigger_creation_query
FROM (
SELECT  quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema='public'

    )  AS foo WHERE tab_name||'_if_modified_trg' NOT IN (SELECT tgname from pg_trigger where not tgisinternal))

LOOP

    -- can do some processing here
 EXECUTE r.trigger_creation_query;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
  END
 $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get the error - ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables

Comment: There is a duplicate question I answered yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229079/check-if-trigger-exists/39229576#39229576

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_rezultz() RETURNS VOID AS
   $BODY$
    DECLARE
    r RECORD;
    BEGIN
 FOR r IN (SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER ' || tab_name|| '_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ' || tab_name|| ' FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ' AS trigger_creation_query
FROM (
SELECT  quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema='public'

    )  AS foo WHERE tab_name||'_if_modified_trg' NOT IN (SELECT tgname from pg_trigger where not tgisinternal))

LOOP

    -- can do some processing here
 EXECUTE r.trigger_creation_query;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
  END
 $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```