# I would like to know which table stores the create statement of a trigger for event trigger eg

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

For example, I create such a trigger:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin 
ON ddl_command_start 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE event_trigger_begin ( );
```

From which table can now be pulled in the same form? Or in parts at least. 
information_schema.triggers does not contain it since it is an event trigger, rather than an ordinary trigger.

Comment: See [How to check if trigger exists in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33174794/1995738)

Comment: This will work with normal triggers but I need to event triggers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if trigger exists in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174638/how-to-check-if-trigger-exists-in-postgresql)

Comment: This does not work for event triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample:

```
et=# create or replace function event_trigger_begin() returns event_trigger as $$ begin raise info '%',99; end;$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 27.611 ms
et=# CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin
ON ddl_command_start
EXECUTE PROCEDURE event_trigger_begin ( );
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER
Time: 18.293 ms
et=# create table i (i int);
INFO:  99
CREATE TABLE
```

You can use `pg_catalog` relation to generate DDL for event_triggers, smth like:

```
et=# SELECT format('CREATE EVENT TRIGGER %I ON %s EXECUTE PROCEDURE %I()',evtname,evtevent,evtfoid::regproc) as ddl
FROM pg_event_trigger;
                                               ddl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin ON ddl_command_start EXECUTE PROCEDURE event_trigger_begin()
(1 row)
```

and lastly the right way to get definition:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ pg_dump -d et -s | tail -20

CREATE FUNCTION event_trigger_begin() RETURNS event_trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$ begin raise info '%',99; end;$$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.event_trigger_begin() OWNER TO vao;

--
-- Name: tr_event_begin; Type: EVENT TRIGGER; Schema: -; Owner: vao
--

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin ON ddl_command_start
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.event_trigger_begin();
```

of course dbname will be not et and tail will not work - I used it jsut to truncate output

Comment: Please, tell me how a request will look on sql only.

Comment: @Виктор no worries, please approve and/or upvote if answered