# PostgreSQL INSERT from SELECT limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a INSERT query and expected 400k rows to be inserted.

But after execution I have 257k inserted.

My expectation from this query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM daily_checkups WHERE pig_migration_count = 0
```

result is 400k

Can somebody explain me, why after insert I have less rows?

```
insert(<<-SQL.squish)
  INSERT INTO pig_migrations (daily_checkup_id, created_at, updated_at, migration_type, amount)
  (
    SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, 4 as migration_type, 0 as amount
    FROM daily_checkups WHERE pig_migration_count = 0
  )
SQL
```

Comment: I wrote. Result - 400k

Comment: How many rows did pig_migrations have before the INSERT?

Comment: 19444, but I think it is not important

Comment: Is there any triggers on pig_migrations table?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you get any  error mesages while exection the SQL like dupplicate key?

Comment: It would be best if you show the definition of the daily_checkups and pig_migrations tables (columns, constraints)

Comment: The most likely cause is a trigger that rejects some of the rows. [How to check if trigger exists in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33174794/1995738)

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I would recommend finding one insert statement that does not get inserted. Than check the values against existing table and check the output messages when this insert is run... If nothing is shown and the row is not inserted go to DB logs and check it up...